# Chrome Extensions: Saving multiple IDs into chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome Extension to store multiple picture IDs on click, although I don't know the best way to store each 'pictureID'

Anyone have experience with chrome.storage that can assist? Thanks!

Comment: read the official docs and show us your attempt and what exactly isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

It's really quite trivial.

`chrome.storage.sync.set({"key":"value"}`

(or use **local** instead of **sync**) will set the stored value of `key`. No other keys will be changed.

`chrome.storage.sync.set({"key1":"value", "key2":"value", }`
will set two keys, etc.  To get them back you can use `.get()` with the key you want, or with null to get all keys in a single object.

Comment: what if you don't know what the key names are? How do you get them?

Comment: It was not correctly answered since it's not checked. Your answer was supposed to be something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42602554/how-to-use-dynamic-keys-in-chrome-local-storage-get-and-set